# Django loading page that uses signals?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a long process wherein my application communicates with a server, saves a model based on the server's response, and restarts its communication. I'd like to present the user with a loading page which updates whenever a model is saved. For example:

```
Working on request 1...
Saving model 1...

Working on request 2...
Saving model 2...

Finished task. 
[Back to Homepage]
```

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317219/django-show-loading-message-during-long-processing)(jango - show loading message during long processing) and its links; the first suggestion would not work, and the second requires threading, caching, etc. I've also read through the documentation for `Signals`.

Let's say the model which is saved is `ModelAfterResponse`. My view might look like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ModelAfterResponse)
def loading_page(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    model_name = kwargs['instance'].name
    return render(request, 'name/javascript_template.html', {"name": name}, content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

And the `javascript_template.html` might look like this:

```
<script>
$('#some_loading_page_specific_div').innerHTML = "Working on " + {{ name }}
</script>
```

This is just quick mock-code—but do I have the gist of it? When I decorate a function as above, and do something simple like `return HttpResponse(":D")`, nothing happens—everything continues running and `:D` is nowhere to be found.

I believe I'm on the right track. Is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: No, unfortunately you are not on the right track. This is not what signals are for and you cannot render data from one. Anything that renders data needs to be in a view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ah, bummer. If you don't mind my asking, what *are* signals used for, if not this? Also, is there a means of updating a page in the way I intend without having to reload the page/stop the process? I'm not sure how to call AJAX from within a view (or why I would want to if I'm already in the view!)

Comment: Signals can be for doing things like updating the database or sending emails. I don't understand what you mean about calling Ajax from within a view though; you call Ajax from your HTML.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ah. What I meant was something like: In order to call AJAX when a model is saved (which updates a loading page), I would presumably need to trigger something HTML related from within the view (when the model is saved). If I use `return HttpResponse(<script>[etc.]</script>)`, this would stop the for loop. I'm not sure how I could go about updating the loading page w/o using signals, and w/o returning something from the view