# How to display dynamic page before task complete in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have two pages in Django, I want to display a page while a task is being done and display second page after it complete how can I do:

**views.py**

```
render(request, 'loading_page.html')
data_processing()
return render(request, 'list.html')
```

Page one (loading_page.html) I that want to display while I am processing data.
After executing that data_processing function, I want to display list.html, How can I do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - show loading message during long processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317219/django-show-loading-message-during-long-processing)

Comment: No, me Are two files to load

Comment: do you think adapt the JS code to set the `window.top.location.href` variable to the loading page url then when the loading is done set the url to the list page?

Comment: You'll need to do that with javascript via ajax.